# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'img_to_array'

Tags: machine-learning

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.models import model_from_json
import json

img_width, img_height = 150, 150
with open('model_architecture.json', 'r') as f:
    model = model_from_json(f.read())


model.load_weights('second_try.h5')
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
image = cv2.imread('/home/hduser/Desktop/IITDPalmprint/training_data/class1/002_5.bmp', 0).astype(np.float32) / 255
plt.title('image')

kernel = cv2.getGaborKernel((121, 121), 4.0, 0, 10.0, 0.5, 0, cv2.CV_32F)
kernel /= math.sqrt((kernel * kernel).sum())
img1 = cv2.filter2D(image, -1, kernel)
x = image.img_to_array(img1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the variable name `image` in your code, while you also import a module named `image`. This conflict results in trying to find `img_to_array` method in the variable rather than in the module.

Use a different name for you `image` variable, or directly import the `img_to_array` function:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
[...]
x = img_to_array(img1)
```